# Jekyll fonts differ betweeen local host and github pages

Tags: css, fonts, sass, jekyll, google-font-api

I'm trying to get the resume-template jekyll theme working. My github repository is here: https://github.com/earlbellinger/earlbellinger.github.io

I'm running into an issue that the fonts displayed on my local machine when I use `bundle exec jekyll serve` are completely different from the ones displayed when github pages render it. How can I fix this? Thanks for any tips.

Comment: What font do you see after building on your local machine? And on production?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[You're experiencing Mixed content security rules!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content)

In `_includes/head.html`, change : http://fonts.googleapis.com
to : https://fonts.googleapis.com

Comment: You saved the day. Thank you!